# Want to download file from S3 Bucket in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3, mean-stack

My problem is that I want to download file from s3 bucket and save it to my local in Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet download file using got and save it to filename.ext

```js
const got = require("got");
const { createWriteStream } = require("fs");

const url = "https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/filename.ext";

got.stream(url).pipe(createWriteStream('filename.ext'));
```